# Date datatype not showing HH:mm:ss in phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

I currently have a row in my data base with 2 date datatype columns.  When I do a select and get those columns back I am only able to see the 'YYYY-MM-DD' I was wondering if it was possible to see the 'HH:mm:ss' as well.
I should also mention the data is there because I am able to filter at the minute level when doing my select.

```
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      PATH        |     START_TIME      |      END_TIME       | 
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| /a/b/c           | 2015-07-13          | 2015-07-13          | 
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#date_type

> The binary representation is an 8 byte long (the number of milliseconds from the epoch), making it possible (although not necessarily recommended) to store more information within a DATE column than what is provided by java.sql.Date

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

> public int getHours()
>   Deprecated. 
>   This method is deprecated and should not be used because SQL Date values do not have a time component.

It appears that they store the time, but subsequently retrieve the Date into `java.sql.Date` which does not have a time component.

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

> There are three classes of datetime data types defined within this
>            International Standard:

```
     -  DATE - contains the <datetime field>s YEAR, MONTH, and DAY;

     -  TIME - contains the <datetime field>s HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND;
        and

     -  TIMESTAMP - contains the <datetime field>s YEAR, MONTH, DAY,
        HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND.
```

Furthermore, the SQL specification does not support time components in a Date column. I recommend using a Timestamp column to comply with SQL specs.